# Discord Python Rewrite - Slice Display Name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a working AFK code, but i need it to slice (delete) '[AFK]' if the user sends a message. The code is:

```
@client.command()
async def afk(ctx, *, message="Dind't specify a message."):
    global afk_dict
    if ctx.author in afk_dict:
        afkdict.pop(ctx.author)
        await ctx.send('Welcome back! You are no longer afk.')
        await ctx.author.edit(nick=ctx.author.display_name(slice[-6]))

    else:
        afk_dict[ctx.author] = message
        await ctx.author.edit(nick=f'[AFK] {ctx.author.display_name}')
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You're now AFK.")
```

I got no errors. i only need `await ctx.author.edit(nick=ctx.author.display_name(slice[-6]))` to be working and i'll be happy.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a `on_message` event. Something like this should work.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author in afk_dict.keys():
        afk_dict.pop(message.author.id, None)
        nick = message.author.display_name.split('[AFK]')[1].strip()
        await message.author.edit(nick=nick)
```

I also recomend you to store user id's instead of usernames.
To do that you just have to use `member.id` instead of `member`.

Comment: I mean, it helps, but i need it to remove the '[AFK]' on the user nick so it will be "nick" instead of "[AFK] nick"

Comment: that still dindt do anythong;-;